# How to add a TextBox in a specific cell in GridView in ASP web forms?

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, gridview, webforms

This question may look repeating but I'm having a slightly different challenge. I have a `GridView` with multiple columns. The first column is a `Button` column and the rest are populated from the database.

**Problem Statement:**
When a user clicks the `Edit` button on a specific row, a `TextBox` should appear in the column called `UnitRate` in the `GridView` `gv2`. The default text of the `TextBox` should be the value / text of that same cell. This `TextBox` should appear only for that specific cell not for the entire column. The current `GridView` is shown below.

[image]

And I want something like this
[image]

Code for `GridView`

```
 <asp:GridView ID="gv2" runat="server" Font-Size="Small" OnRowCommand="gv2_RowCommand">
           <HeaderStyle BackColor="Yellow" />
           <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="LightGray" />
           <RowStyle BackColor="LightGray" />
           <Columns>
                 <asp:TemplateField>
                      <ItemTemplate>
                           <asp:Button ID="btn_edit" runat="server" Text="Edit" CssClass="btn btn-warning btn-sm" CommandName="editData" CommandArgument='<%# Container.DisplayIndex %>' />
                      </ItemTemplate>
                 </asp:TemplateField>
           </Columns></asp:GridView>
```

Comment: Post the code that you have tried which did not give you what you want.

Comment: What is the markup for your GridView? Are you using template columns? Are you open to using template columns if not? Are you using the RowEditingEvent? What do you want to happen once the user has entered the new value? How will you let your application know that the user has finished entering the info? Are you open to a JavaScript/jQuery solution?

Comment: @JonP I am using `TemplateField` for the button.I am using `RowCommand` event where I want the `TextBox` to be shown. Once a user has entered the value he has to press an `OK` button in the form below the `GridView`

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/1e050f/edit-and-update-record-in-gridview-in-Asp-Net/

You can use the EditItemTemplate to make that UnitRate field a text box when the user clicks edit. You can then make the EditItemTemplate for all the rest of the fields to just be a label. The drawback is that you have to spell out all the columns explicitly rather than having them autogenerated, but that's unavoidable if you want something non-standard like this to happen, where one field is editable while others aren't.